# Passing parameter to LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-5

I have a method like below:

```
public void GetUserIdByCode(string userCode)
{
    var query = from u in db.Users
                     where u.Code == userCode // userCode = "LRAZAK"
                     select u.Id;

    var userId = query.FirstOrDefault(); // userId = 0 :(
}
```

When I ran the code, I got the default value of 0 assigned to userId meaning the Id was not found.
However, if I changed the userCode with a string like below, I will get the value I want.

```
public void GetUserIdByCode(string userCode)
{
    var query = from u in db.Users
                     where u.Code == "LRAZAK" // Hard-coded string into the query
                     select u.Id;

    var userId = query.FirstOrDefault(); // userId = 123 Happy days!!
}
```

My question is why passing the parameter into the LINQ query does not work? 
When I stepped into the code, I got the SQL statement like so:

```
// Does not work...
{SELECT "Extent1"."LOGONNO" AS "LOGONNO"FROM "DEBTORSLIVE"."DEBTORS_LOGONS" "Extent1"WHERE ("Extent1"."LOGONCODE" = :p__linq__0)}
```

The hard-coded LINQ query (the working one) gives an SQL statement as below:

```
// Working just fine
{SELECT "Extent1"."LOGONNO" AS "LOGONNO"FROM "DEBTORSLIVE"."DEBTORS_LOGONS" "Extent1"WHERE ('LRAZAK' = "Extent1"."LOGONCODE")}
```

What would be the solution?

Comment: Can you show the code calling `GetUserIdByCode` please ?

Comment: I suspect the value wasn't *actually* `LRAZAK` - I suspect it had a space at the start or end, or something like that.

Comment: which type is u.Code in db?

Comment: You should try sanitizing the input to make sure nothing weird is in the `userCode` string.

Comment: @Bun The code calling the method is nothing fancy. Just passing a string. Initially it was a string from a property of an object but using a simple string does not work.

Comment: @JonSkeet wbennett I did step through the code and the variable on has a string "LRAZAK"

Comment: @Timsen the type for u.Code is string
The method works fine if I replace the passed parameter with a literal string in the query...

Comment: Did you check that the length was 6? Consider non-printing characters...

Comment: I am very confident and almost absolutely certain that the value is clean. I even tried `string usercode = "LRAZAK"` and passed `usercode` to the query and still no joy...

Comment: What type is the u.Code on the DB?

Comment: @wbennett It's Oracle data type CHAR(20 BYTE)

Comment: As a work-around, I use [Dynamic Linq](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: I would be excited to see if you can make a smallish program that can replicate this.  Did you even try to ``.Trim()`` the parameter or anything?

Comment: @KyleGobel The input was clean. I think it has to do with the limitation of the LINQ not being able to take variable in constructing the query in order to make it dynamic

Answer (score -1):

As a work-around, I use [Dynamic Linq](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/).
The code below is working for me.

```
public void GetUserIdByCode(string userCode)
{
    string clause = String.Format("Code=\"{0}\"", userCode);

    var userId = db.Users
                        .Where(clause)
                        .Select(u => u.Id)
                        .FirstOrDefault();    
}
```

The database query returns an object of `User` with `Code` and `Id` as properties. This is defined in one of my classes.

Answer (score -2):

Here is syntax that will work to pass an argument to a LINQ query.

Not sure how many people will be searching this topic so many years later, but here's a code example that gets the job done:

```
string cuties = "777";
    
    // string collection
    IList<string> stringList = new List<string>() { 
        "eg. 1",
        "ie LAMBDA",
        "777"
    };
    
    var result = from s in stringList
                where (s == cuties) 
                select s;
    
    foreach (var str in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str); // Output: "777"
    }
```

Comment: This is not related to the question which has to do with query translation into SQL.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question was "What would be the solution?"

Comment: Correct, that's the question. This is not the answer. Where's the SQL translation?

Comment: Look at the title of the post   LINQ stands for Language INtegrated Query.  When the correct LINQ syntax is used, the necessary database language is generated whether it's SQL or many other database languages.  LINQ is the translator.  If you need the SQL, you can step into the code like the poster did.  Besides, the SQL translation is pretty basic - are you trolling?